# A question of arithmetic regarding erection cost of a structure.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> The current erection cost of a structure is Rs. $13,200$. If the labour wages per day increase by $\frac 1 5$ of the current wages and the working hours decrease by $\frac 1 {24}$ of the current period, then the new cost of erection in Rs. is

$(A)\ 16,500$.

$(B)\ 15,180$.

$(C)\ 11,000$.

$(D)\ 10,120$.

I have got an answer different from the answer which is approximately equal to $16528$. Which is very close to option $(A)$. Is it correct? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Attempt:

Labour wages increment is proportional to erection cost and working hours decrement is reverse proportional to the erection cost.

So the required erection cost is $13200×\frac{\frac65}{\frac{23}{24}}$
 which simplifies to $16528$
 (approx.)

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! Please tell us how you got the answer of $16528$. Explaining what you did will help us understand where you went wrong and allow us to give you more assistance.

Comment: What's that? Just at the very beginning $3$ downvotes. Who are bloodies?

Comment: Unfortunately, the community can be kind of harsh against questions that don't follow our Guidelines. Your question would be higher-quality if you showed your work and explained how you got to your answer. I apologize for the swift downvotes from others, but I would suggest adding your work to your question in order to improve it.

Comment: Labour wages increment is proportional to erection cost and working hours decrement is reverse proportional to the erection cost.

Comment: So the required erection cost is $\frac {13200 \times \frac 6 5} {\frac {23} {24}}$ which simplifies to $16528$ (approx.).

Comment: I see. Why is the decrease in working hours inversely proportional to erection cost? If working hours decrease, then you have to pay your workers less wages, so erection cost should also decrease.

Comment: But it will simultaneously take much time than before. So I have to pay extra labour wages as well.

Comment: No, if working hours decrease, then they are saying the construction of the building will take less hours of work, so you will be paying your workers for less time and labour costs will decrease.

Comment: No, when working hours decrease, it does not mean the number of days you work increase. For example, let's say the company buys new technology that makes workers work 15% faster. Then, less time is needed in order to do the same amount of work on the building and working time decreases by a factor of $1.15$.

Comment: Suppose I decrease working hours to $t$ then for this we have to take $d$ (say) extra days to complete the structure.Suppose the actual days needed is $d'$. Suppose the labour costs decreases to $r$. Suppose the original wage were $w$ then how do you guarantee that $r(d+d') < wd$?

Comment: Again, it does not take any extra days to complete the structure. Some technology has made the laborers' work more efficient, so the working hours can decrease and the building will still be completed in the same amount of time.

Comment: But if workers do $15$% faster than before then they may demand $15$% more money than what they actually get.

Comment: But no technology is assumed in the question.

Comment: math maniac: Please add your work and thoughts in  an ***edit*** to your question, and not only in comments.  Else, it is bound to be overlooked.  In any case, the information you've added in comments is what belongs in your question post, as it is the question post that is posted that is and will be evaluated.

Comment: No technology has been mentioned, but I feel like you have to make some inferences as to why working hours decrease in order to understand the question. Also, yes, if workers work faster, they may demand more money. This is why, in the problem, wages increase by $\frac 1 5$. In any case, question does not mention that the number of working days increase, so you have to assume that the number of days stays the same.

Comment: So you have two contradictory startements. Right? Working days decrease $\implies$ labour wages increase as well as decrease. Funny statement. Isn't it so? Which one I assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we assuming that the total number of hours needed remain the same, then indeed your solution is correct, that is the answer is

$$13200 \times \frac65 \times \frac{24}{23} \approx 16528$$

which unfortunately not one of the option.

However, suppose for some reason, their efficiency improves and the days needed remains the same, then the answer is $$13200 \times \frac65 \times \frac{23}{24}=15180.$$

This is a badly framed question where the setting is not clear.

Just FYI, $13200 \times \frac65 \times \frac{25}{24}$ gives you the first option but it is not correct.

I am aware of the background of the question which is from GATE, the answer key is $B$, hence they have assumed that the number of days required remain the same.

Comment: Yeah this is what I have said. The efficiency of the workers cannot be improved all of a sudden. So the second case that you and Noble Mushtak have mentioned is somewhat absurd unless some extra conditions were given in the question. Isn't it so @Siong Thye Goh.

Comment: Seems like a question understanding problem now, rather than a maths problem.

Comment: Yeah!  You are right!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the increase in erection cost is proportional to the increase in wages, so the new cost after wages increase is:

$$13,200\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{5}\right)=15,840$$

Now, the decrease in working hours is actually proportional to the decrease in wages because if the working hours decrease, then since the workers are on an hourly wages, the amount you need to pay the workers also decreases, so the erection cost decreases. Thus, the new cost after wages increase and hours decrease is:

$$13,200\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{5}\right)\cdot (1-\frac{1}{24})=13,200\cdot\frac{6}{5}\cdot\frac{23}{24}
=15,180$$